# Selecting all patterns in text

Tags: java, regex

I would like to display all rows from a text, but at the moment i display only second row. The error is in my rowRegex :(.
I will be very grateful for any help.

My code:

```
package test.jpa;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class FireTest {

    public static void main(String[] arStrings) throws Exception {

        String str = "*PureNG*#"
                   + "\"*Part*\":https://pure1.pdf** \"Part1\":https://pure2.pdf** \"Part2\":https://pure3.pdf** \"Part3\":https://pure4.pdf#"
                   + "\"*Fakt*\":https://pure5.pdf** \"Fakt1\":https://pure5.pdf** \"Fakt2\":https://pure6.pdf#"
                   + " \"*WZ* _(wydanie)_\":https://pure7.pdf#"
                   + " \"*ZA*\":https://pure8.pdf** \"PA\":https://pure9.pdf#"
                   + " \"*Close*\":https://pure11.pdf** \"Close1\":https://pure12.pdf#"
                   + " \"*Stany*\":https://pure13.pdf</text><version>7</version><author id=\"1\" name=\"UserName LastName Admin\"/><comments></comments> <created_on>2015-11-26T15:08:26Z</created_on><updated_on>2015-11-30T15:44:00Z</updated_on></wiki_page>";

        String rowRegex = "(#.*?#|\\Z)";
        Pattern patternRow = Pattern.compile(rowRegex);
        Matcher matcher = patternRow.matcher(str);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Finded: " + matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment that's my result:

```
Finded: #"*Part*":https://pure1.pdf** "Part1":https://pure2.pdf** "Part2":https://pure3.pdf** "Part3":https://pure4.pdf#
Finded: # "*WZ* _(wydanie)_":https://pure7.pdf#
Finded: # "*Close*":https://pure11.pdf** "Close1":https://pure12.pdf#
Finded:
```

but I would like to get the follow output:

```
Finded: #"*Part*":https://pure1.pdf** "Part1":https://pure2.pdf** "Part2":https://pure3.pdf** "Part3":https://pure4.pdf
Finded: #"*Fakt*":https://pure5.pdf** "Fakt1\":https://pure5.pdf** "Fakt2":https://pure6.pdf
Finded: # "*WZ* _(wydanie)_":https://pure7.pdf
Finded: # "*ZA*":https://pure8.pdf** "PA":https://pure9.pdf
Finded: # "*Close*":https://pure11.pdf** "Close1":https://pure12.pdf
Finded: # *Stany*\":https://pure13.pdf</text><version>7</version><author id=\"1\" name=\"UserName LastName Admin\"/><comments></comments><created_on>2015-11-26T15:08:26Z< created_on><updated_on>2015-11-30T15:44:00Z</updated_on></wiki_page>"
```

Comment: Could you please post the input in readable format? Thanks!

Comment: @Derek,  please consider accepting the answer that worked best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex must look like

```
String rowRegex = "#[^#]++";
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/6jUWLN)

The `#` matches a literal `#` and `[^#]++` will match 1 or more symbols other than `#` (possessively).

If you need to discard the first `#`, use a capturing group `#([^#]++)` and access the first group with `matcher.group(1)`.

Comment: @Derek, any news? Did you have time to check my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"(#?.*?#|\\Z)"
```

so you need #?, instead of #